# Rendered HTML not in sync with React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm currently creating a custom React component in Meteor for adding images to a list (and later uploading them). However when I try to delete images from the list, always the last element is removed from the GUI. Initially I thought this was just a simple case of using the wrong index for deletion, but it turned out to be more than that.

This is what my `ImageList` component currently looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import cloneDeep from 'lodash.clonedeep';
import { ImageItem } from './image-item.js';

export class ImagesList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.values = this.props.images || [];

    this.onDrop = this.onDrop.bind(this);
    this.addImages = this.addImages.bind(this);
    this.deleteImage = this.deleteImage.bind(this);
    this.imageChanged = this.imageChanged.bind(this);
  }

  onDrop(files) {
    this.addImages(files);
  }

  onDropRejected() {
    alert('Invalid file type');
  }

  addImages(files) {
    files.forEach(file => {
      this.values.push({
        title: '',
        description: '',
        url: file.preview,
        file,
      });
    });

    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  deleteImage(index) {
    console.log('index to delete', index);
    console.log('images pre-delete', cloneDeep(this.values)); // deep-copy because logging is async
    this.values.splice(index, 1);
    console.log('images post-delete', cloneDeep(this.values)); // deep-copy because logging is async
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  imageChanged(index, image) {
    this.values[index] = image;
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    console.log('--------RENDER--------');
    return (
      <div className="image-list">
        <div className="list-group">
          {this.values.length === 0 ?
            <div className="list-group-item">
              No images
            </div>
            :
            this.values.map((image, index) => {
              console.log('rendering image', image);
              return (
                <ImageItem
                  key={index}
                  image={image}
                  onDelete={() => { this.deleteImage(index); }}
                  onChange={(item) => { this.imageChanged(index, item); }}
                  deletable={true}
                />
              );
            })
          }
        </div>
        <Dropzone
          multiple={true}
          onDrop={this.onDrop}
          onDropRejected={this.onDropRejected}
          className="dropzone"
          activeClassName="dropzone-accept"
          rejectStyle={this.rejectStyle}
          accept={'image/*'}
        >
          <span>Drop files here</span>
        </Dropzone>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The `ImagesList` component can be initialized with some values (for the sake of debugging), which it uses during rendering. For example:

```
<ImagesList images={[
  { title: 'Image 1', description: 'Image 1 description', url: 'http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/3/3yiC6Yq.jpg' },
  { title: 'Image 2', description: 'Image 2 description', url: 'http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/4/40Ly3VB.jpg' },
  { title: 'Image 3', description: 'Image 3 description', url: 'http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/0/00kih8g.jpg' },
]}/>
```

`ImagesList` renders an `ImageItem` component for each image. This is what this component looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { RIEInput, RIETextArea } from 'riek';

export class ImageItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.placeholder = {
      title: 'Title',
      description: 'Description',
    };

    this.value = this.props.image;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="list-group-item">
        <div className="text-content">
          <h4>
            <RIEInput
              className="description"
              value={this.value.title.length <= 0 ?
              this.placeholder.title : this.value.title}
              change={(item) => {
                this.value.title = item.value;
                this.props.onChange(this.value);
              }}
              validate={(value) => value.length >= 1}
              classEditing="form-control"
              propName="value"
            />
          </h4>
          <span>
            <RIETextArea
              className="description"
              value={this.value.description.length <= 0 ?
              this.placeholder.description : this.value.description}
              change={(item) => {
                this.value.description = item.value;
                this.props.onChange(this.value);
              }}
              validate={(value) => value.length >= 1}
              classEditing="form-control"
              propName="value"
              rows="2"
            />
          </span>
        </div>

        <img className="thumb img-responsive"
          style={{width: '20%' }}
          src={this.value.url}
          alt="Image"
          data-action="zoom"
        />

        {this.props.deletable ?
          <div className="delete-btn">
            <span onClick={this.props.onDelete}>
              &times;
            </span>
          </div>
          :
        undefined }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Let's say I have three images, image A, B and C, and I want to delete image B. After pressing the delete button, **image C** will disappear from the GUI instead.

Inside the `deleteImage()` function of `ImagesList`, I am logging the index that is to be deleted and also log the values before and after the deletion. The index that is logged is correct, in this case that is index `1`. Before the deletion the values are images A, B and C. After deletion the values are images A and C, as they should be.

I decided to do some logging inside the `render()` function of `ImagesList` as well. Unfortunately this also logs the correct values A and C, but **A and B** are actually rendered.

I have also tried to use the React state for this component instead of storing it in a local variable in conjunction with `forceUpdate()`.

Another thing I have tried is to use the React Developer Tools plugin for Chrome. The Devtools also show the correct values, but the GUI still does not, as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHDAr.png).

I'm currently out of ideas on what to try, any help would be appreciated!
Using the snippets I provided, you should be able to create a Meteor project and reproduce this bug.

Comment: In general, you should trigger a change to the images on the origin of those images. Since they were given to you as props, then the change should not happen in the component itself. This is usually done by a triggering an action and then using a global state manager to update the state that is mapped to the `props`. I am curious as to where you have seen component update being done the way you demonstrate in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MasterAM's suggestion I managed to find two different solutions.

---

*A.)* **Using `componentWillUpdate()`**

The `this.value` variable is set only once namely in the constructor of the `ImageItem` component. To ensure that changes are properly delegated, you have to update `this.value` inside the `componentWillUpdate()` function. Something like:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  this.value = nextProps.image;
}
```

---

*B.)* **Using the property directly**

This is definitely the more proper solution. Here we get rid of the local variable `this.value` inside the constructor of the `ImageItem` component.

Inside the `render()` function you replace `this.value` with `this.props.image`. Now **without** having to use the `componentWillUpdate()` function, everything works as expected.